# Laravel Dusk (Chrome Selenium) - take full page screenshot (while preserving viewport height styling)

Tags: laravel, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

With Laravel Dusk (Chrome Selenium driver) normal screenshot covers just the size of the window. All other issues specify taking a full-height screenshot by making the window size match the size of all the content (`body` element). However, when there are elements that are styled using viewport height unit, extending the window height doesn't help and still doesn't show all of the page.

Is there a way to take a full-page screenshot in this case? Perhaps it's possible to extend the window height while "freezing" the CSS rendering/updating, or take a screenshot of the whole page without changing the window height?

Thanks!

Comment: The only way I found so far is to take a lot of screenshots while scrolling through the page and then combine them all into a single image. Works well unless there are any animations or scroll-height-based styling on the page, in which cases the images don't really align well.

Answer (score 0):

i don't believe this is possible will advise you to when it fails to than edit the test to perform an `scrollIntoView($selector)` or an `mouseOver($selector)` and after that use the `screenshot` method